# How to replace string based on partial match in dataframe, pandas, python

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe. One column is the occupation column. There are dozens of different ways a `real estate` related occupation is represented in this column. Every representation has the word `real` in it.

I want a simple line of code that partially matches to every instance of `real` and replaces it with `realestate`.

Right now, I have close to 60 instances of:

```
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestateholding','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestatemgmt','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestateagent','realestate')
```

And so forth. I've cleaned the data with:

```
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].apply(lambda x : x[12:])
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.lower()
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.strip()
```

The lambda function removes a preceding `Occupation` string in each cell.

Another oddity is that when I run this cell, it changes most the first time I run it. But I have to rerun the cell about 5 times to get everything. A complete list of all my `replace` functions are below. Some of these I wrote before I cleaned the `dataframe` with `lower()` and `strip()`.

```
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('RealEstate','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('REALESTATE','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('CommericalRealEstate','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('RealEstateDeveloper','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realtor','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('Realestateagent','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('RealEstateConsultant','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('Real-estate','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('RealEstateConsulting','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('RealEstateInvestment','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('DirOperat/MultiplanRealEstate','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('RealEstateCompany','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('RealEstateBroker','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('Commercialrealestate','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestateConsultant','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestateConsulting','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestateDeveloper','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestateInvestment','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('DirOperat/Multiplanrealestate','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestateCompany','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestateholdings','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestateinvestor','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestateinvestment','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestatedeveloper','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestatemanagers','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestatebroker','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('commercialrealestate','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestateholding','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestatemgmt','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestateagent','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestateholdingco.','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestatedev. co.','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestate co.','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestatedev.','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('marine/realestate','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realtyinvestment','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realty co','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestate.','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestateco.','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestatevest','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestateest','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestatest','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestatet','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestatement','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestateainment','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestateinment','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('investments/realestate','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestatent','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestatenment','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realtycompany','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realpropertytitle','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('investmentsrealestate','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('developmentrealestate','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestates','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('transportation/realestate','realestate')
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestateies','realestate')                   
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].str.replace('realestatees','realestate')
```

Comment: `df.loc[df['Occupation'].str.contains('real'), 'Occupation'] = 'realestate'`.

Comment: If you posted that as an answer instead of a comment, I'd flag it as being correct.